# Will the spouse freak out if she finds out you are a werewolf or vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so I recently became a werewolf. Now let's say I wanted to marry ysolda or Camilla. If I did get married to them and I turned into my wolf form, will they freak out towards me or should I just hide that little part of me?

Comment: Save before hand, then try it. If they do freak out, reload the save

Comment: Marry Aela. She won't mind. You can make freaky wolf love.

Answer (score 5):

In general, yes, they will.

**Werewolves**

According to [Elder Scrolls Pages article on Lycanthropy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy),

> As a werewolf in Skyrim, you will be hated and feared by almost any NPC that sees you in your beast form, and most will attack you on sight (exceptions include other werewolves, M'aiq the Liar, members of the Dark Brotherhood, The Circle, followers currently in your service, members of the Thieves Guild, and the heroes of Sovngarde, **but not your spouse, unless your spouse is one of these**).

So, if your spouse is in a faction that doesn't care, then they don't care. Being a spouse doesn't affect it.

This leaves you a number of options, including Aela the Huntress, also a werewolf.

**Vampires**

The [Elder Scrolls Pages article on Vampirism](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism) says that

> Vampires are hated and feared by the general population and stage four vampires will be attacked on sight. The four major joinable factions will not be hostile toward stage four vampires so long as you join before you reach stage four and are not caught feeding on any of their members. With Dawnguard installed, NPCs will only attack you if you are in Vampire Lord form.

Whether you have Dawnguard or not has a big impact on how NPCs treat vampires. The above excerpt doesn't explicitly mention spouses, but it sounds like the same situation as with werewolves. If they're in a faction that isn't going to attack you then they won't, otherwise they will.

Note that with Dawnguard, you can actually turn your spouse *into* a Vampire in the quest [The Gift](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Gift). It says there that "Your spouse will turn hostile if you turn into a vampire lord in front of him or her". I'm not sure if that's before turning them, after, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out as a vampire dawnguard or not, feeding on your spouse apparently doesn't upset them or make them hostile. I just bit Muiri while not in stealth mode and she didn't mind.

Comment: She probably read Twilight, saw you doing it and went "Hot."